# Getting a handle on iOS's alert view controller by tel:// prompt

Tags: ios, swift, openurl, tel, uialertviewcontroller

On iOS, opening a `tel` link via

```
func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

or the older (for iOS 9 and older)

```
func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool
```

will make iOS display an `UIAlertViewController` and present it to the user on your behalf.

I can't seem to find a way to get a handle on this `UIAlertViewController`. I'd like to know when it's showing and when it's not.

Usually, if you instantiate and present a `UIAlertViewController` yourself, you can see if its displaying because

```
self.presentedViewController
```

will not be `nil`.

Essentially, there is a behavior I'd like to "pause" when a system-displayed alert is shown (such as the `tel` prompt) and then "resume" when it is dismissed.

I've looked around Apple's documentation and cannot seem to find anything on this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't get the alert since it is presented by iOS outside of your app.  You will get a `willResignActive` and `didBecomeActive` delegate callback and `Notification`

Comment: I was afraid of this but it's certainly better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: @MarioAGuzman This alert from the system side, you can't do anything right now. I mean current APIs does not allow to interact to this behavior. The system holds all of the responsibilities. From the release [notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/) of iOS SDK 10.3:   openURL When a third party application invokes `openURL`: on a `tel://`, `facetime://`, or `facetime-audio://` URL, iOS displays a prompt and requires user confirmation before dialing.